# Checkbox default as selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to set that while creating new entity in View the checkbox will be always set to selected(true) by default?

In viewmodel its:

```
public bool AutoBlock {get;set;}
```

In view I rendering it:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AutoBlock, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AutoBlock, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AutoBlock, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In your viewmodel add this `model.As = true;
return View(model);` and then in your `@Html.CheckBoxFor` add this : `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.As);`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a viewmodel, then just set the value to true in your constructor.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        AutoBlock = true;
    }

    public bool AutoBlock {get;set;}
}
```